# microsoft wireless mobile mouse 4000 wheel click problem!

Tags: mouse-wheel

when i click wheel button, i expect to close tabs, or open link new tab, but this mouse opening (alt+tab) running task dialog. what can i do? i suppose uninstall driver solving problem but this time back button dosnt work prp

Comment: The question is clear enough to me, because this is my problem right now. MS Wireless Mouse 4000/5000 sets up middle click by default to open "Instant Viewer" (which is somewhat akin to alt+tab in that it shows you all currently running apps). But the poster (and myself) just want the original middle click behaviour back. In Chrome, this will close a tab (if you click on the tab) and open a link in a new tab. Luckily Matthew Lock has the answer.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you click the mouse wheel is a setting in Control Panel -> Mouse -> Buttons -> Wheel button

Change Wheel Button to Middle Click

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This was tricky: I was looking at that list for ages without understanding what "middle click" meant.